# Angulardart show HTML String

Tags: html, angular-dart

This question is probably really stupid but i really searched a lot for it, but I may be using the wrong keywords.
I have a String with `<hr>` and I want Angular to display a horizontal line.
The HTML is converted to `<hr>` and therefore displayed as text `<hr>` on the page.
How can I achieve this that the HTML tags are not converted by angular?
I have done this in Angular 6 with TS and there it was no problem, is there a pipe or something else, which I have to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding to `[innerHtml]` should do that.

```
<div [innerHtml]="fieldInComponentClassWithHtml"
```

Comment: Angular might strip some HTML it deems insecure. There should be some docs how to convince Angular to trust the passed HTML. Just on the phone right now. Add a comment if you can't find it.

Comment: Thanks. i guess you mean: https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts.

Comment: Exactly. Interesting that they use `innerHTML` instead of `innerHtml`. That might have changed in Dart2. (I worked mostly in Flutter projects the past year)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SafeInnerHtmlDirective
https://pub.dev/documentation/angular/latest/angular.security/SafeInnerHtmlDirective-class.html